# Voting button - on_hover function does not work for $.get results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I've added a liking/disliking function my comics website.

I've made custom graphics for it.

- When a user hovers over selection, it will change, then swap back off hover...
- When a user clicks, it will swap images until they click the same vote again, where it will switch back to the original.

---

So, before they've clicked, I run a function `getVoteImages();` which queries Vote table to see if the user has voted before.

- If they've voted like, the shirt will be green, and dislike shirt will be white.
- If they've voted dislike, the dislike shirt will be red, and like shirt will be white. If no vote, both shirts are white.

When the hover over, the javascript below will swap images as such:

[image]

Here is the output HTML from Chrome: You can see that onhover, `this_hover();` is correctly called and the image changes:

```
<img src="./images/SiteDesign/liked.png" id="like" onclick="callBoth(this.id)">
<img src="./images/SiteDesign/dislike_hover.png" id="dislike" onclick="callBoth(this.id)" onmouseover="this_hover(this.id)">
```

---

When a user clicks, it will call a javascript function which will run a jquery $.get AJAX call to a likecounter.php script which will load the vote into the db, and increment either likes or dislikes. Doing this will first hide ( `$("#like, #dislike").hide();` ) and replace the original vote image with the updated vote... so either a green shirt for like, red shirt for dislike, or white shirts if not selected. You cannot have a vote for both like and dislike.

[image]

The $.get AJAX will output updated voting images to `<span id="choice"></span>`. So below, in outputted HTML, you can see the original voting images are hidden `style="display: none;"`, and the replacement images are display in `<span id="choice"></span>`. **This is strange because the replacement images include the same `onmouseover` call...**

[image]

**The issue:**

The output HTML looks correct... so I'm not sure why the hover function isn't being called again when the result is returned from the server.

I've even tried putting in `alert(id);` to test if the functions are even being called when the voting images are returned from the $.get, and the ID is alerting out just fine.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function this_hover(id) {
        alert(id);
        var images = {
            "like": [
                "./images/SiteDesign/like_hover.png",
                "./images/SiteDesign/like.png", 
            ],
            "dislike": [
                "./images/SiteDesign/dislike_hover.png",
                "./images/SiteDesign/dislike.png",
            ]
        }
        $("#"+id).on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                if (this.id in images) this.src = images[this.id][0];

            },
            mouseleave: function() {
               if (this.id in images) this.src = images[this.id][1];
            }
        });
    }

    function callBoth(choice) {
        likeCounter(choice);
    }

    function likeCounter(choice) {  

        $.get("./scripts/likecounter.php", {_choice : choice, _site : "<?php echo $site; ?>", _id : <?php echo $imgid; ?>},
            function(returned_data) {
                $("#choice").html(returned_data);
            }
        );
        $("#like, #dislike").hide();
        $("#getlikes").hide();
    }   
</script>
```

Any thoughts why the image swap won't work when click on a vote? Why is the `alert(id)`working, but not the `$("#"+id).on({ .....` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I shouldn't be hiding the original images... I should remove them so the mouseover over the hidden images doesn't conflict with the replacement images from $.get:

So this: `$("#like, #dislike").remove();`

Instead of this: `$("#like, #dislike").hide();`